# In C# how to get value from text box using quotes

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

In my program i need to get value from the database , so using a texbox so that client type anything and i can search from database.

My code is

```
 SqlCommand sqlcmd = sqlcon.CreateCommand();
 sqlcmd.CommandText = "Select distinct transactionName from dbo.tbl where terminalId = " + textBox_cardNumber.Text;
```

the above is not my full code but here in my code i am using textbox_cardNumber ...

I want that in quotes ''

it should be like

`Select distinct transactionName from dbo.tbl where terminalId = '0097'`

So my question is how to get in quotes???

Comment: SQL injection, you should use Sql param

Comment: You are highly susceptible to SQL injection.  Use paramaterized queries....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [a parameterized query](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) like this

```
SqlCommand sqlcmd = sqlcon.CreateCommand();
sqlcmd.CommandText = "Select distinct transactionName from dbo.tbl " + 
                     "where terminalId = @id";

sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id",  textBox_cardNumber.Text);
....
```

In this way you defer the job to recognize your data (the textbox text) as a string to the Framework code that knows how to correctly quote your value. Also you remove the possibilities of [Sql Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work) attacks

Answer (score 4):

```
  "'" + textBox_cardNumber.Text + "'";
```

I hope I understood you!

Comment: `it should be like Select distinct transactionName from dbo.tbl where terminalId = '0097'` single quotes, not double.

Comment: Yeah, saw it just when you said. Sorry!

Comment: Why don't you use the Parameters property of the Sqlcommand itself?

Comment: @thefiloe It is not the best way to do it, I know! It was just as I read the question, I did not exactly watch the problem on SQL.

Comment: Well. So you'd better do something like this: `String.Format("...'{0}'...", textBox_cardNumber.Text)`

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this, but this is not good practice, used always Parameter.

```
sqlcmd.CommandText = "Select distinct transactionName from dbo.tbl where terminalId = '" + textBox_cardNumber.Text +"'";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:

```
SqlCommand sqlcmd = sqlcon.CreateCommand();
sqlcmd.CommandText = "Select distinct transactionName from dbo.tbl where terminalId = '"
+  textBox_cardNumber.Text+"'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of string concatenation, you <strike>can</strike> **should** use *[parameterized sql](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html)* instead. Because this kind of codes are open for *[SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)* attacks.

```
SqlCommand sqlcmd = sqlcon.CreateCommand();
sqlcmd.CommandText = "SELECT DISTINCT transactionName FROM dbo.tbl
                      WHERE terminalId = @terminalID";

sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@terminalID", textBox_cardNumber.Text);
```

A side note, take a look at [*SQL Injection Attacks by Example*](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of prepared statements in which you use parameters.

Otherwise, you need to add quotes around your input string, but it will leave you open for SQL injection